# IdentityServer4 & Windows Authentication

Tags: windows-authentication, identityserver4

I've been chasing this problem around for a while now and I can't get to the bottom of it.  I've read the other solutions on here (https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io and https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI) and it's still not working, so I've tried to reduce this down to the absolute basics.  This is not the actual problem I am facing, but produces the very same outcome.  i.e. I can't get Windows Authentication to work.

1. I clone https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples
2. I amend `Quickstarts/7_JavaScriptClient/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs` so that `WindowsAuthenticationEnabled` is `true`
3. I then goto http://localhost:5000/account/login and attempt to use the Windows external provider and I get 401.

The only difference with this simple sample here, and what I see on my actual system is that I'm getting challenged for credentials on my real site.

Debugging the code I never see `if(HttpContext.User is WindowsPrincipal)` succeeding, because it's always a `ClaimsPrincipal`.

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have windows authentication enabled on your IIS site? This needs to be enabled for your WindowsPrincipal to be assigned. Note that windows authentication only works when running behind IIS or IIS Express.

Comment: Yes, windows authentication is enabled on IIS.  I've got it running Kestrel with the UseIISIntegration, so I'm guessing IIS is acting as a reverse proxy for this.

Comment: IIS or IIS Express? Enabled for the site or for the server? I ask because HttpContext.User is WindowsPrincipal works fine, so this is most likely an environment issue.

Comment: Wow...  I had Windows Auth enabled for the Site and Application, but when I enabled it for the Server it all sprang into life.  Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/windows.html does good job on explaining exactly what steps are needed to light up Windows Authentication.